# Using RANK() OVER() where the over is the results of a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have the following query that produces some numbers that I want to rank, here is the query.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, 
round((((select cast(count(mentions.id) as decimal) 
from mentions, events 
where mentions.event_id = events.id AND
events."startDate" < (to_date('2017-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') -180) AND
mentions.person_id = a.id)
/
(select cast(count(mentions.id) as decimal) 
from mentions, events 
where mentions.event_id = events.id AND
events."startDate" < (to_date('2017-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') -180) AND
mentions.person_id = 79)) * 100), 1) as lagged_person
FROM events, people, mentions
WHERE
events.id = mentions.event_id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.name
```

Essentially I need to be able do something like RANK() OVER(lagged_person), when I put that as my next "column" after the lagged person I get an error that says lagged person does not exist. What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you have a cartesian product with the `people` table? You really want the output to be duplicated as many times as you have `people` records?

Comment: It's a comparison of the number of times a person showed up to an event divided by the number of times their boss showed up to an event (the 79 is the boss id it's generated by my app) that gives me the lagged person, essentially I want to rank that.

Comment: Do a select qry.*,rank() over (partition by lagged_person) from (your current query ) qry

Comment: @Nikhil That should be `ORDER BY lagged_person`, otherwise an excellent `answer`

Comment: @itsLex - Yes agreed I just wanted to show how it can be done. :)

Comment: You have `a` as an undefined alias. That query is invalid. you should provide details of your schema, sample data and expected output for that sample.